# How can I prevent unwanted changes when I add a link to something?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

My page has links on different text and images, to take you back to the home page, on to other pages, etc.  I'm trying now to update them and have found that when I hover on any of these linked items a grey bar appears behind it.  I have tried altering the a:hover bit of my CSS code but have not been able to find a way to get rid of this unwanted effect.  I'd eventually like it to look like nothing on the page itself has changed, but maybe that the mouse changes as you hover on the link.

A summarized sample:

HTML:

```
 <div id="example">
     <a href="homepage.html"><img src="images/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
     <h3><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></h3>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
a:link {color: #333; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #666;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;color: #C30;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;}
```

The div container contains no wording that would affect the links.  The solution is probably pretty simple but so far searches on this have been unhelpful.

Comment: What browser are you using...? And can you show a sample of the page?

Answer (score 0):

**Like this...?**

http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/QHcP3/1/

```
 <div id="example">
     <a href="homepage.html"><img src="http://www.phawker.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/dudewtf.thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
     <h3><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></h3>
 </div>

a:link {color: #333; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #666;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;cursor:crosshair;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The color in your :visited rule should match the color in your :link rule if you want them to look the same.

`a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #666;}`

should be

`a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #333;}`